# How to use a variable from a bean, in a HTTP url in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I'm new to Camel and have been using it only for past couple of days.

I want to Do some processing in a bean "retreiveDetails" and then use a variable "idValue" from that bean "retreiveDetails" in the next step in route, which is a http url. A part of Routebuilder class is as follows,

```
 .to("bean:retreiveDetails?method=process")
   .to("http://10.80.80.90:51555/patients?id=${idValue}")
    .to("bean:empiResults?method=process")
```

How do I set the value of "idValue" in the bean "retreiveDetails"? And how do I use it in the route in Routebuilder?

Comment: you can pick dynamic values from body/properties/headers. E.g id=${body.idValue} if idValue attribute exists in body. If idValue itself your body, then simply use id=${body}.

Comment: @BalakumarNarayanasamy Thank you, using ${body} worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ about using dynamic values in to:
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html